# Write Objective-C directly in Unity Project?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm trying to create an app, where at one point, uses native OS functions depending on the mobile platform. For instance, when a user is using iOS, and they tap the 'Email' button, then a UIAlertView will pop up. And so on and so forth for Android, Blackberry, Windows8/8Phone.

I want to be able to write all the code in MonoDevelop (don't need to access code from XCode or Eclipse projects). I've added the proper code for iOS so far, and laid the framework for the other platforms. Hopefully there is a way for the compiler to know that this code is not C#, and will run natively on the platform indicated... So does anyone know if there is a way to basically do this?:

```
#if UNITY_IPHONE

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email Us"
                          message:@"Would you like to send us an email?"
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    #endif

#if UNITY_ANDROID

    #endif

#if UNITY_BLACKBERRY

    #endif

#if UNITY_WINRT // windows 8, or windows 8 phone

    #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can develop some of it in MonoDevelop. So for the iOS, you can throw some source files in your Assets/Plugins/iOS folder and they will get included as plugins (See http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html).

Unfortunately, for Android, your Java files need to be compiled in to jar files (See http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html). So you won't be able to do it all in MonoDevelop.

Though if you really wanted to get fancy, you could probably put your java files in your plugins folder and when you are done making edits in MonoDevelop, you could execute a custom script (Maybe an ant script) that compiles the files in that directory for you.